# How to hide specific columns in the grid column menu (ExtJS 6.5.3)?

Tags: extjs, grid, hide, extjs6, extjs6-classic

I have a grid, which has some columns that are set hidden. However, if I click on the column head and open up the menubox it shows all columns in the column section. It also includes those columns that are set hidden in the grid itself. My question is how I can remove those columns from this list as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set hidden to true and hideable to false. That will hide the column and omit it from column menu.